# Is it possible to add top/side shading to a graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2010, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar graph in Excel that's basically a steeped line graph, or a bar graph that only has top and side shading. Sort of like this:

```
        #### 
        #
        #
     #### 
     # 
     # 
     #
     #
  ####
  #
  #
###
#
#
#
#
```

where the line is dark gray and everything else is white. Is it possible to make a graph like this in Excel?

I can already do it by using two graphs, where the bottom graph uses gray bars with 0 gaps and the top graph uses white bars and then makes everything else transparent, and then setting one top of the other with offset, but it looks really hacky.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question to add a link to a screen cap of the desired result? (you can upload it to imgur.com and post a link to it, someone with enough reputation will likely embed it in the question for you)

Comment: I can't unfortunately, this post is from my phone. I tried to make an ASCII art to show what I mean. Something that literally looks like a steeped line like that but instead of hashtag signs, it's a solid gray line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

1. Generate your bar chart
2. Use a white fill for the bars:

[image]

3. Under effects, choose `Shadow` and get an Outer Shadow:

[image]

4. Adjust transparency, Blur, Angle and Distance to taste, do *not* adjust the size %

You should get something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is _perfect_, it looks as desired when I use a between-bar gap size of 0. Thanks so much